# Trying to determine the distances between centroids of countries R

Tags: r, distance, country-codes, centroid

I currently have a dataframe of pairs of country codes (like US, RU, CA etc.) Is there a function that determines the centroid of a country given the country code so that I can find the distance between the pairs of countries? Or is there a function that can give me the coordinates of the centroid of each country (such as the longitude and latitude for example)?

This is the first couple lines of my dataset that I had filtered from a previous one for reference.

[image: This is the first couple lines of my dataset that I had filtered from a previous one]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scrape this [google public dataset](https://developers.google.com/public-data/docs/canonical/countries_csv).
My previous suggestion to use the `countryref` dataset in package [`CoordinateCleaner`](https://ropensci.github.io/CoordinateCleaner/reference/countryref.html) doesn't work because I found out there are duplicates with different positions.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url <- 'https://developers.google.com/public-data/docs/canonical/countries_csv'
webpage <- read_html(url)
centroids <- url %>% read_html %>% html_nodes('table') %>% html_table() %>% as.data.frame

data <- data.frame(V1 = c("US","US"), V2 = c('VN','ZA'))
data %>% inner_join(centroids,by = c("V1"="country")) %>% inner_join(centroids,by = c("V2"="country"))

  V1 V2 latitude.x longitude.x        name.x latitude.y longitude.y       name.y
1 US VN   37.09024   -95.71289 United States   14.05832   108.27720      Vietnam
2 US ZA   37.09024   -95.71289 United States  -30.55948    22.93751 South Africa
```

Comment: From looking over the package details, my understanding is the package consists of a dataset that I can then use to map to the country codes I have in my own dataframe. Is this correct?

Comment: I think so, we can check this if you provide in your question an example of your dataset : dput(head(yourdataset))

Comment: I added a picture of the first couple lines of my dataset if that is helpful.

Comment: after trying to integrate your dataset, I found out that `countryref` had duplicates, see my proposed alternative. By the way, when sharing a dataset, it's better to copy the result of `dput(head(dataset))` than putting an image, because I could have copied this right away in my code.